# Onclick event is not working on first click

Tags: javascript, html, css

When the page loads I need to click the button twice to trigger the `onclick()` function. After doing so, everything works as expected.

As I am new to this web development field I would highly appreciate the detailed explanation.

Thank you in advance.

```js
var hamburger = function() {
  var menu = document.getElementById('menuBarSlide');
  if (menu.style.right == "-300px") {
    menu.style.right = "0px";
  } else {
    menu.style.right = "-300px";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="navMenuItem hamburger" onclick="hamburger()">
  <span class="ham-icon"></span>
  <span class="ham-icon"></span>
  <span class="ham-icon"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Try defining the function as `function hamburger()` instead of putting the function in a variable like that. You don't need that kind of approach looking at your code. You can use `var hamburger = function()` elegantly if your function returns an object and you have to instantiate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that `menuBarSlide` is the id of a `div`, if so this should work for you.

I've added some styling to highlight the `div`, and a `console.log()` to be sure that the code executes.

**Edit**: Maybe the problem is that you expect the element to have a value in the `right` property but it is different, so logging the style can be helpful.

**Edit 2**: The problem is in the initial value (that is why your first click is not working, so with this variation `menu.style.right = menu.style.right || "-100px";` that problem is solved. **That line of code assigns -100px if the value comes null**. Additionally, the program logs the value before and after the conditional assignment.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>menuBarSlide</title>
    <style> 
        #menuBarSlide {  /*To highligth your div*/
            position: absolute;
            background-color: grey;
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="navMenuItem hamburger" onclick="hamburger()">
       <span class="ham-icon">Item1</span>
       <span class="ham-icon">Item2</span>
       <span class="ham-icon">Item3</span>
    </div>

    <div id="menuBarSlide">
      <h1>menuBarSlide</h1>
    </div>

    <script>
        var hamburger = function() {
            var menu = document.getElementById('menuBarSlide');

            console.log("before assing: " + menu.style.right); // To check the current style of the element

            menu.style.right = menu.style.right || "-100px"; // Assign -100px if is null, otherwise keep the same value

            console.log("after assing: " + menu.style.right); // To check the style after the asigment

            if (menu.style.right == "-100px") {
              menu.style.right = "30px";
            }    
            else {
              menu.style.right = "-100px";
            }
        }
    </script>

<body>
<html>
```

Comment: tried it,it is executing the code but not working on first click still

Comment: Your code is fine, the problem is that `menuBarSlide` have a value different that you are expecting or have no value at all. If you click multiple times on the `div` you will find that the aligment change in every click.

Comment: That is why is a good idea to use `console.log(menu.style);`.

Comment: Then that means menu.style.right isn't actually -300px on start? Take this guy's advice, check the `menu.style.right` on console so you can see the value initially

Comment: i have used console.log(menu.style); the intial value is -300px and it should change to 0px on first click but it is showing -300px on first click and from second click it is working just fine.

Comment: @vihar take a look at the update that I've made, pay special attention to the line `menu.style.right = menu.style.right || "-100px";`.

Comment: it is working now , thank you very much for the help @AlejandroMontilla

Comment: @vihar If it is working, please accept and upvote the answer, so we get some reputation, and other may find/use this answer in the future.